# Yii: controller id and module are null

Tags: url, yii, controller, action, yii-url-manager

***Edit***: Yii version 1.1.14

I'm trying to get current module / controller / action and manually build an url since the call to

```
$url = Yii::app()->urlManager->parseUrl(Yii::app()->request)
```

is not working as I'd except upon path format.

Why should I need that? because when I hit an url having a list view, by assigning the pagination->route property in the CActiveDataProvider constructor to Yii::app()->urlManager->parseUrl(Yii::app()->request) will produce the following effect:

1. Clicking the "page 1" item (or the "previous" item while being on page 2) will redirect to "$url"
2. Clicking another link would redirect to "$url/page/(pageNumber)".

BUT when the urlFormat is PATH, my $url will have GET parameters embedded, if any. This is: if currently I'm in page 2 (it also applies to any page not being the first), the current url will be:

**(module)/(controller)/(action)/page/2** (2 or whatever)

and the generated link for page X (for X > 1):

**(module)/(controller)/(action)/page/2/page/X**

and the generated link for page 1:

**(module)/(controller)/(action)/page/2**

which is problematic since I cannot get back to page 1.

So I tried the following approach: Generating programmatically the [module/]controller/action route by accessing the current controller object data (**no: assigning the urls manually is NOT an option**):

```
$module = $controller->module ? $controller->module->id : ''  
$controller = $controller->id  
$action = $controller->action->id
```

BUT even when the current route (yes, in my browser url) is admin/accessLog/list (module, controller, action) and my url parsing rules are like this:

```
'urlFormat'=>'path',
'showScriptName'=>false,
'rules'=>array(
    array('admin/admin/index', 'pattern' => 'admin'),
    array('client/client/index', 'pattern' => 'client'),
    array('admin/admin/<action>', 'pattern' => 'admin/<action:(login|logout|index|profile)?>'),
    array('client/client/<action>', 'pattern' => 'client/<action:(login|logout|index|profile|recoverPassword)?>'),
    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
    '<action:\w+>' => 'site/<action>'
),
```

(*Yes, there's an admin app inside an admin module, and the same for client app. but please remember the current url starts with admin/accessLog/list. This doesn't mean that it doesn't occur in other urls: it only means I'm currently working with this url, so take it as a starting point*)

$module is empty (should be "admin"), $controller is empty (should be "accessLog"), and action is "list" (expected value).

My currently installed modules are (application-level):

```
'modules'=>array(
    'gii'=>array(
        'class'=>'system.gii.GiiModule',
        'password'=>'developer',
        'ipFilters'=>array('127.0.0.1','::1'),
    ),
    'admin'=>array(),
    'client'=>array(),
),
```

***Edit***: And my currently installed ***modules*** are:

/admin/ module:

```
Yii::setPathOfAlias('admin', dirname(__FILE__));

class AdminModule extends CWebModule {

    public $defaultController = 'admin';

    public $controllerMap = array(
        'catalog' => 'admin.controllers.AdminCatalogController'
    );

}
```

/client/ module:

```
Yii::setPathOfAlias('client', dirname(__FILE__));

class ClientModule extends CWebModule {

    public $defaultController = 'client';

    public $controllerMap = array(
        'catalog' => 'client.controllers.ClientCatalogController'
    );

}
```

And, once again, my question:

Assuming $this is the current controller being an instance of AccessLogController (which is in the module /admin/ and not via an external mapping), why both:

```
$module = $this->module ? $this->module->id : ''  
$controller = $this->id
```

are coming as empty?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

**NEVER** overwrite the __construct($id, $module=null). Overwrite init() instead.
If you deeply need to overwrite the beforementioned constructor (OR are a n00b like me and don't know the init() method), call parent::__construct($id, $module) in the first line or before any side-effect occurs (except you know what are you doing).

init() is called externally after construction (in (CWebApplication instance)->runController(), after creating it in a call to $this->createController).

If you override the constructor but don't do the parent call, properties id and module will be unset, since they are not set externally by the application.